# Rails: How to test code in the lib/ directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have a model which gets its data from a parser object. I'm thinking that the parser class should live in the lib/ directory (although I could be persuaded that it should live soewhere else). The question is: Where should my unit tests for the parser class be? And how do I ensure that they are run each time I run rake test?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the Rails application I'm working on, I decided to just place the tests in the `test\unit` directory. I will also nest them by module/directory as well, for example:

```
lib/a.rb   => test/unit/a_test.rb
lib/b/c.rb => test/unit/b/c_test.rb
```

For me, this was the path of last resistance, as these tests ran without having to make any other changes.

Comment: @Qqwy since this does not work on Rails 5, what is the best practice for testing `lib` on Rails 5.2.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know. :-(

Answer (score 23):

Here's one way:

Create `lib/tasks/test_lib_dir.rake` with the following

```
namespace :test do

  desc "Test lib source"
  Rake::TestTask.new(:lib) do |t|    
    t.libs << "test"
    t.pattern = 'test/lib/**/*_test.rb'
    t.verbose = true    
  end

end
```

Mimic the structure of your `lib` dir under the `test` dir, replacing lib code with corresponding tests.

Run `rake test:lib` to run your lib tests.

If you want all tests to run when you invoke `rake test`, you could add the following to your new rake file.

```
lib_task = Rake::Task["test:lib"]
test_task = Rake::Task[:test]
test_task.enhance { lib_task.invoke }
```

Comment: Somehow it doesn't load up the environment (specifically `ActiveSupport`'s `fixtures`), and there's not way to force it in rakefile.

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution and `rake test:lib` runs my test, but `rake test` does not. I copied it verbatim. Here's a link to my file contents: http://pastebin.com/FHMXU6vG Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

I was looking to do the same thing but with rspec & autospec and it took a little digging to figure out just where they were getting the list of directories / file patterns that dictated which test files to run.  Ultimately I found this in lib/tasks/rspec.rake:86

```
  [:models, :controllers, :views, :helpers, :lib, :integration].each do |sub|
    desc "Run the code examples in spec/#{sub}"
    Spec::Rake::SpecTask.new(sub => spec_prereq) do |t|
      t.spec_opts = ['--options', "\"#{RAILS_ROOT}/spec/spec.opts\""]
      t.spec_files = FileList["spec/#{sub}/**/*_spec.rb"]
    end
  end
```

I had placed my tests in a new spec/libs directory when the rpsec.rake file was configured to look in spec/lib.  Simply renaming libs -> lib did the trick!

Comment: I have `/lib` by default in my project somehow.
Unfortunately `rake test` does't catch up the files, so this is RSpec-only and I have to use the solution above.

Answer (score 3):

An easy and clean way is just to create a directory under test/unit/lib.  Then create test as test/unit/lib/foo_test.rb corresponding to lib/foo.rb.  No new rake tasks required, and you can nest more directories if needed to match the lib directory structure.

Answer (score 3):

As of [Rails 4.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake#L73):

```
rake test:all         # Run all tests in any subdir of `test` without resetting the DB
rake test:all:db      # Same as above and resets the DB
```

As of [Rails 4.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake#L16), redefine `test:run` to include additional tasks when running `rake` or `rake test`:

```
# lib/tasks/test.rake

namespace :test do
  Rake::Task["run"].clear
  task run: ["test:units", "test:functionals", "test:generators", "test:integration", "test:tasks"]

  ["tasks"].each do |name|
    Rails::TestTask.new(name => "test:prepare") do |t|
      t.pattern = "test/#{name}/**/*_test.rb"
    end
  end
end
```

This has the added bonus of defining `rake test:tasks` in the given example.

As of [Rails 4.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake#L17), `test:run` includes all subdirs of `test` including them when running `rake test`, and thus `rake`.

Comment: In Rails 5, these different tasks no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

To not define additional rake tasks to run tests from the custom defined folders you may also run them with the command `rake test:all`. Tests folders structure for the `lib` folder or any other custom folder is up to you. But I prefer to duplicate them in classes: `lib` is matched to `test/lib`, `app/form_objects` to `test/form_objects`.

Answer (score -3):

Use:

```
[spring] rake test:all
```

to run all tests, including the directories you created (like `[root]/test/lib/`).

Omit `[spring]` if tou aren't using it.

Comment: rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'test:all'